# How to create a square matrix given 3 columns i data frame- R

Tags: r, matrix, out-of-memory, bigdata

I am struggling to figure out how to develop a square matrix given a format like

| user_id | book_id | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3234 | 1234567892 | 5 |
| 5567 | 0000252564 | 7 |

To something like:

| book/user | 3234 | 5567 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567892 | 5 | 0 |
| 0000252564 | 0 | 7 |

in R. i tried to use 'Matrix' method but my data frame is too big (1,000,000 records).
how can i do that?

Comment: `out <- reshape::cast(df,book_id~user_id,value="rating")` . Then  
`out[is.na(out)] <- 0`

Comment: `reshape2::dcast(df,book_id~user_id,value.var = "rating",fill = 0)`

Comment: How many distinct values do `user_id` and `book_id` have? If there are too many, it will not be easily possible as the result could get very big. Otherwise just use `reshape::cast` or `tidyr::pivot_wider`